# How to take file from a branch, and push them exactly has if in my branch

Tags: git, github, gitkraken

I have 2 branch. a branch A that was a "upgrade" branch, and a branch B that is the stable branch.

Many changes were made to branch A progressively, and many merge of B inside A were made.

Now, branch A work ok, and everything has been update, so I would like to keep all the new files and changes on certain files, but revert some to the exact version in branch B

How can I do that ?

tl;dr : I have a file in branch B that was modified and change and merged in branch A multiple time. I would like to copy the file from banch B and override the one in branch A without applying eventual change made in branch A

Comment: How about a switch to branch B copy file and then switch back to A and past this file then just make a commit?

Comment: that is kind of what I am doing, but there are multiple file, It s taking some time ^^

Answer (score 0):

When at branch A, you can check-out a specific file from branch B.

That is

```
git checkout B file.h
```